# CPPointOfInterestTemplate update

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I need to show empty CPPointOfInterestTemplate, then call my backend, and then update earlier created CPPointOfInterestTemplate.
What should I do with this CPPointOfInterestTemplate on start? I have tried

```
var poiTemplate = CPPointOfInterestTemplate(title: "Parkings", pointsOfInterest: [] , selectedIndex: NSNotFound)
```

and later

```
poiTemplate.setPointsOfInterest(poisFromBackend, selectedIndex: NSNotFound)
```

but I see San Francisco location on the map, and after get data I see that poi list has been changed, but map is still on San Francisco.

Any idea?